# Changing many textboxes' background color on user input

Tags: c#

I got up to 10 textboxes and I want them to change BackColor on user's input.

at the moment I use this current code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "1")
    {
        textBox2.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = false;
        textBox4.Visible = false;
        textBox5.Visible = false;
        textBox6.Visible = false;
        textBox7.Visible = false;
        textBox8.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text == "2")
    {.......
```

But making this for 10 (or more) boxes is taking too long time.

Comment: What is taking time, the actual writing of it or the programs performance? is these the only 10 boxes? is the logic just to set the colour of the "next" textbox?

Comment: @Sayse Sorry for the bad description.. The actual writing would be it as I am going to add more textboxes (100+ or more).

Comment: @Xakzi - The actual logic involved is still unclear, How do you determine which box needs its colour/visibility changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an approach as  follows:

```
Control[] controls = { textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8 };
int controlNum;
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out controlNum)
    && controlNum > 0 && controlNum <= controls.Length)
{
    Control activeControl = controls[controlNum - 1];
    activeControl.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
    activeControl.Visible = true;
    foreach(Control unactiveControl in controls.Where(c => c != activeControl))
        unactiveControl.Visible = false;
}
```

If you instead want to apply the changes on the number of controls the user has specified:

```
int controlCount;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out controlCount)
    && controlCount > 0 && controlCount <= controls.Length)
{
    var activeControls = controls.Take(controlCount);
    var unactiveControls = controls.Skip(controlCount);
    foreach (Control activeControl in activeControls)
    {
        activeControl.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        activeControl.Visible = true;
    }
    foreach (Control unactiveControl in unactiveControls)
    {
        unactiveControl.BackColor = Color.Black;
        unactiveControl.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would probably only make one of the textboxes DarkRed as I want the number which the user select to color as many textboxes..
So if user choose number 5 then textbox 1 to 5 should be colored darkred

Comment: Wow such fast answers. I belive this will do.. Going to study it and remember/learn it. Edit it to make it of use for future usage.

Answer (score 2):

Start by adding all the textboxes whose colour/visibility needs to be changed into a panel.

Once they are all in you can use the following

```
int counter;
if(!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out counter))
    return;

int currentCounter = 0;
foreach(var tb in panelName.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if(currentCounter++ < counter)
    {
        tb.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        tb.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        tb.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: also, ussing `Tag` property as a controller for finding appropriate TextBoxes would be nice

Comment: @Ham3d - I disagree since that could possibly be laborious and error prone, by adding the desired controls to a panel it should mean you never need to touch this logic again

Comment: maybe there is some other TextBoxes that shouldn't change at all but they are in the same panel

Comment: @Ham3d - But as the first sentence in my answer states, they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the amount of code you're going to write is to turn it on it's head a bit.  Instead of thinking 'if textbox1 is "1" then set textbox2 visible', think 'when should textbox2 be visible?'

As an example, and based on the limited logic you've shown:

```
textbox2.Visible = textbox1.Text == "1";
```

This will set visible to `true` when `1`, otherwise `false`.

Comment: sorry about the limited logic.. But the amount of code would be a lot less with this. Will try out a few things with this and what Tim Schmelter commented and see what I can do with it.